# How does this zend framework path work?

Tags: php, windows, apache, zend-framework, path

I'm using the zend community server on windows vista.  I'm following the tutorial in the book Zend Framework 1.8 by Keith Pope.

```
$this->_view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/main.css');
```

is not finding the main.css file (404).  The actual file path is htdocs/myapp/public/css/main.css   . When i take out the slash and change it to

```
$this->_view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('css/main.css');
```

it works fine.  However when look up an example of the appendStylesheet function in the zend docs, it uses the example

```
$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/styles/basic.css')
```

So it seems to me what right now "works" for me is incorrect.  Any ideas on why this is so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you take out the slash, the "< base />" tag will also affect where your stylesheets are loaded from. If the base tag is non-existent, then the css will be loaded relatively to where you are (i.e.: http://localhost/myapp/ will load css from http://localhost/myapp/css/main.css when you're not using slash in the include)

From your description, I think your document root is pointing to myapp/ instead of myapp/public/ and you've got your < base href="" /> configured to '/myapp/', therefore actually loading the css from '/myapp/css/main.css' when not using the slash.

Also, check the path of your document root.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, the document root was set to myapp instead of public

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
 echo $this->baseUrl();
```

before you output

```
 echo $this->headLink();
```

.
So in layout it will be like

```
 echo $this->baseUrl() . "/" . $this->headLink();
```

Or

[Git Code](https://github.com/harikt/zendblog/blob/master/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml#L10)

Hope it helps.